# TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropType from 'prop-types'`
Counter.propTypes = {
caption: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
initValue: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
Counter.defaultProps = {
caption: null,
initValue: 0
};
```

[Cannot read property 'string' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceXI5.png)

Comment: You're not passing the prop to your component. Can you post the code for your component and how you're using it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post errors as images, but instead, put the stack trace inline in the question, so we can see it better. It also can help us get better context as for what's actually going on.